# How to grab what collection a product belongs to?

Tags: shopify, liquid

i am trying to get the collection a product belongs to when running a loop but all it returns is collectiondrop as the output. example:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
{{ product.collections }} //each product belongs to one collection only.
{% endfor %}
```

this is on a products page, such as related products. so when i try something like this:

```
{{ product.url | within:collection }}
```

it grabs the current collection that im viewing for a product and it has no corelation to the product that was listed. so the resulting url becomes

```
/product/item-name
```

instead of

```
/collection/some-name/product/some-product-name
```

which is what im looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if products belongs to a single collection, the collection object is still an array, so you should call it like so:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
{{ product.collections[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Have in mind that you must specify what you want from the collection or it will return collection drop, so for example `{{ product.collections[0].url }}` will do OK.

When you are stuck in such way use the `json` filter to check what is the object returning ( when in this example it will probably not allow you to see the object json ).

Comment: makes sense thanks! , what if i want to use it as a filter? would within:collections[0] work or i would have to do something else?

Comment: this works better thanks alot! :)   {{ prod.collections[0].url }}/products/{{ prod.handle }}